# Rust linker errors: using "-Wl,--as-needed" when linking system libraries

Tags: rust, linker, gtk

I'm trying to write an application primarily in rust that uses a gtk-based frontend written in C++. I've gotten pretty far in getting the build setup in Cargo, but it's failing in the linking stage.

I've created a minimal reproducible example.

```rs
// build.rs

extern crate cc;
extern crate pkg_config;

fn main() {
    let gtk = pkg_config::probe_library("gtk+-3.0").unwrap();
    cc::Build::new()
        .cpp(true)
        .file("src/gui.cc")
        .includes(gtk.include_paths)
        .compile("gui");
}
```

```cpp
// src/gui.cc

// This is essentially the first example from https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/getting_started.html

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

extern "C" {
int run_gui();
}

static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer) {
  GtkWidget* window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int run_gui() {
  GtkApplication* app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), nullptr);
  int status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), 0, nullptr);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

```rs
// src/main.rs

extern "C" { 
    fn run_gui() -> core::ffi::c_int;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { run_gui(); }
}
```

When I `cargo build` the package, compiling the c++ and rust files seems to work fine, but then I get undefined reference errors on the link stage.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/pete/workspaces/csvtk/so-minimal-gtk/target/debug/build/so-minimal-gtk-75c7a9a61d32d2e6/out/libgui.a(gui.o): in function `activate(_GtkApplication*, void*)':
          /home/pete/workspaces/csvtk/so-minimal-gtk/src/gui.cc:9: undefined reference to `gtk_application_window_new'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/pete/workspaces/csvtk/so-minimal-gtk/src/gui.cc:10: undefined reference to `gtk_window_get_type'
  ...
```

The link line, which is quite long, is also logged before that error. It includes all the required gtk libraries, `-lgtk-3`, `-lcairo`, etc. When I run it outside of cargo, it fails with the same errors, but, when I remove the `-Wl,--as-needed` flag from the link line, it links correctly and the program runs fine.

Why did rustc add `-Wl,--as-needed`? Is there a reason those gtk symbols aren't "needed" from the perspective of the linker? Any tips on how to fix this problem elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, using `--as-needed` as a flag to the linker is extremely helpful because it prevents your binary from being linked to libraries it doesn't use directly.  As an example of a reason why this is beneficial, if you depend on libfoo 1.0, which depends on libbar 1.0, and later on libfoo 1.1 updates to libbar 2.0, then as long as you don't use libbar directly, your code will continue to work with `--as-needed`, but won't work without it (unless libbar has symbol versioning).

The kind of impact is visible here when you use `objdump -x` on the binary after making the change I suggest below:

```
  NEEDED               libgtk-3.so.0
  NEEDED               libgio-2.0.so.0
  NEEDED               libgobject-2.0.so.0
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  NEEDED               ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

`ldd` lists 70 libraries linked into your program, and you're only directly requiring to 6, including the dynamic linker.

You can usually rely on other crates to specify their link dependencies correctly.  However, you need to be careful because when you're creating your own dependency on a library using C or C++, you have to specify the libraries to link with yourself.  This can be seen if you use `cargo build -v`, where you can notice that your `gui` library is linked *after* the dependencies of libgtk-3:

```
Running `rustc --crate-name test_repo --edition=2021 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=c60f7e6ab8348a08 -C extra-filename=-c60f7e6ab8348a08 --out-dir /tmp/user/1000/test-repo/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/tmp/user/1000/test-repo/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/tmp/user/1000/test-repo/target/debug/deps -L native=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L native=/tmp/user/1000/test-repo/target/debug/build/test-repo-c89dae0927f2103a/out -l gtk-3 -l gdk-3 -l z -l pangocairo-1.0 -l pango-1.0 -l harfbuzz -l atk-1.0 -l cairo-gobject -l cairo -l gdk_pixbuf-2.0 -l gio-2.0 -l gobject-2.0 -l glib-2.0 -l static=gui -l stdc++`
```

So you'd want to do something more like this in your `build.rs`:

```
// build.rs

extern crate cc;
extern crate pkg_config;

fn main() {
    let gtk = pkg_config::probe_library("gtk+-3.0").unwrap();
    cc::Build::new()
        .cpp(true)
        .file("src/gui.cc")
        .includes(gtk.include_paths)
        .compile("gui");
    for path in gtk.link_paths {
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", path.display());
    }
    for lib in gtk.libs {
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib={}", lib);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Deferring those link instructions until after compiling the C++ code did work correctly. I also ended up using `cargo_metadata(false)` to keep `pkg_config` from emitting the link instructions automatically when probing for the library.